# How can I upload a photo to Facebook using Haskell?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, haskell, happstack, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I am using Happstack, and I am trying to upload a photograph to Facebook using the Facebook Graph API.

I can successfully post a message to Facebook. I can use `url`, however I am trying to do this with the `source` parameter.

I have a ByteString of PNG data, but I can't seem to pass it along to Facebook.

I am using the [fb Haskell library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fb-0.7.5).

The functions that I have created to do this are:

```
performPost :: String -> IO Response
performPost code = do
    x <- BS.readFile "test.png"
    performFBAction $ do
        postToFB (BS.unpack x) code =<< getToken url2 code
        return $ toResponse postFB

postToFB :: (MonadResource m, MonadBaseControl IO m) => String -> String -> FB.UserAccessToken -> FB.FacebookT FB.Auth m FB.Id
postToFB dataString code token = FB.postObject "me/photos" [args "message" "Test Post Pls Ignore",
                                                            args "source" dataString] token
```

The error that I receive is:

> The error was "StatusCodeException (Status {statusCode = 400, statusMessage = "Bad Request"}) [("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8"),("Date","Thu, 29 Jan 2015 05:06:00 GMT"),("Connection","close"),("Content-Length","3121")] (CJ {expose = []})

What am I doing wrong? The Graph API states that the `source` parameter should be of type form data, but I have so far been unsuccessful in trying to convert it to such.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether the photo's content is encoded correctly. It need to be `multipart/form-data` as stated on

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos#publish

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Tobi. I've tried to encode the data as `multipart/form` many different ways, but still receive the same error as above every time. Do you have any suggestions as to how to encode the PNG data?

Comment: I'm not a Haskell expert, but did you have a look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.3.9/docs/Happstack-Server-Internal-Multipart.html especially the multipartBody property?

Comment: I've tried that, but I may be approaching the problem incorrectly. I've been trying to encode the data as `multipart/form-data` and send it along as a ByteString as a parameter. Should I somehow be trying to append the multipart to the request itself?

Comment: As I said, I'm not a Haskell export. I'd try to append the multipart directly to the post request, I guess that is what it's for

Comment: I have added the solution to my problem, but I have selected your answer as being correct.

Answer (score 0):

What Tobi said is correct. The code to correctly perform this operation is:

```
postPhoto :: FB.UserAccessToken -> IO Response
postPhoto (FB.UserAccessToken _ b _) = withSocketsDo $ withManager $ \m -> do
    fbpost <- parseUrl $ "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/photos?access_token=" ++ T.unpack b
    flip httpLbs m =<<
        (formDataBody [partBS "message" "Test Message",
                       partFileSource "graph" "graph.png"]
                      fbpost)
    return $ toResponse postFB
```

Enjoy!